# Needing a private and public method for the same recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, methods, private, public

We have recently been working on implementing recursive methods for several classes (trees, heaps, queues, linked lists, etc) in C++ for my computer science class. I have not been having any trouble writing the implementations for the methods, but something my professor mentioned briefly in passing confused me and she never elaborated on the point.

She mentioned that when implementing a recursive function for a class you need to have both a public and private version of that function.

For example (part of a linked list class definition):

```
public: 
  // constructors, destructors
  // member functions etc.
  findMax() { findMax(head); }
private:
  findMax(Node* first_node) { // actual code with recursive calls }
  Node* head;
```

So here there are two functions, one private and one public. All the public function does is call the private function and return whatever it finds to be the answer.

I have a few questions about this.

Is this something you must do?
Does this only apply to class methods that are recursive? If so, what about recursive functions makes this necessary? Would you do this for other functions?

My intuition is that perhaps this is done to ensure that people using the public class methods don't go full dingus mode and end up calling a recursive function with parameters that won't ever lead to a stopping/base case.

Can anyone elaborate on this idea in general and explain it in an intuitive way?

Thanks!

EDIT: Thank you all for your quick answers they have been very helpful! I think I may have misheard my professor and this actually has nothing to do with recursion (though the example she was writing may have been) and is rather just a convention in Object Oriented Programming.

The idea within OOP being that findMax() requires the use of a private class variable (head) to be of use, but would be a handy public function. The private version of findMax(Node* n) then allows a public user to find the max of the list without having the opportunity to access and mess up the private head.

Thanks everyone! Cheers.

Comment: *She mentioned that when implementing a recursive function for a class you need to have both a public and private version of that function.*: Tell her what about the `private` method that does the recursion was named `findMax_recursion()` would it make any difference? My point is that what she said is personal directive not necessarily good practice.

Comment: "*She mentioned that when implementing a recursive function for a class you need to have both a public and private version of that function*" - there is no such requirement in C++.  Maybe that is her requirement, but that is just a coding style.

Comment: The public function is not recursive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"My intuition is that perhaps this is done to ensure that people using the public class methods don't go full dingus mode and end up calling a recursive function with parameters that won't ever lead to a stopping/base case."*

Your intuition is right up to some point. `head` is managed internally with the class, and shouldn't be introduced as a parameter from a caller.

There's no specific relevance to recursion, but rather data encapsulation OOP principles:

`head` should be managed from the class internally, though a function `findMax()` should be available in the public class interface. To provide an appropriate internal implementation the search is delegated to a `private` implementation, which in this case is used recursively. But that doesn't really matter as mentioned.

---

As for your edits in the question. You should put as much code as possible into the `private` function, and leave it narrow. I can't see any reason, why your prof put these in the public function.

Comment: I thought that this was perhaps the case and that it had nothing to do with the recursion. Could you briefly explain the logic behind doing this from an OOP perspective? I feel as if I just about understand why she did this, but I'm still not fully there.

Comment: Thank you so much this makes so much more sense now! I have one more questions I am going to edit into the bulk of the question if you have the time. Thank you thank you!

Comment: @KurtMadland _"I am going to edit into the bulk of the question"_ Please no! Ask one question at a time here please.

Comment: oops sorry okay nevermind then, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> Is this something you must do?

No.

> Does this only apply to class methods that are recursive?

Not even that.

> If so, what about recursive functions makes this necessary?

Nothing.

> Would you do this for other functions?

Yes, I would. It's a choice you make about organising your code. In general, the functions invoked by my `public` class member functions are `private`, unless there's any inherent need for them to also be `public`.

> She mentioned that when implementing a recursive function for a class you need to have both a public and private version of that function.

Assuming this is close to verbatim, your teacher was either wrong or unclear. (It's also possible that she was leaving the element of "choice" for a future lesson; whether this is ethical/reasonable or not is up for debate.)

One might also argue that, in this case, she misled you by giving the two `findMax` overloads the same name; `findMax()` and `findMax(Head*)` are *two separate functions* and you could have (I would have) called the latter `findMaxImpl(Head*)`, or something like that. Then you will see that recursion doesn't have anything to do with this.

> My intuition is that perhaps this is done to ensure that people using the public class methods don't go full dingus mode and end up calling a recursive function with parameters that won't ever lead to a stopping/base case.

Amusingly, your intuition is a lot more sensible here than C++ actually is. :P There is nothing in the language to prevent or even *try* to prevent "full dingus mode". Not really.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: "Not really"? Wow, getting rep on SO is so easy these days! ;)